# Waiting Queue with Multiple Branches

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am currently working on a project and I am looking for a technique that will solve this scenario:

There are people waiting in a room to take one of many tests. There can be multiple tests assigned to each person. Each test may be given at one or more locations at a given time, but only one person can take the test at a given location at a time.

It is relatively simple just to randomly assign people to the tests and eventually they all get done, but what kind of system could I use to make it where people wait a relatively equal time? If I just randomly assign them, a person that only has to take one of the tests could be put behind people that have to take 5.

I have thought about assigning people with a lower number of tests to take first, but I have not yet tested that and it seems like it would still be unfair. And to add complexity, I am adding a feature that allows the priority to be changed.

To be clear, this is not a homework assignment. This project is still in the logical development phase, so I haven't really started programming to compare different techniques. The closest thing that I have thought of would be to create a system that acts somewhat like a thread pool, but I have not found anything that gives a detailed description of the techniques behind a thread pool and it seems that it would require a good bit of overhead and still run into problems if I just used a thread pool directly. I have also looked into the C# Queue class, but I haven't thought of a way to expand its capability.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

C# (and most other languages) has a [concurrent priority queue](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1696822056) that you could use.  Place the test takers on the queue, and remove one (and assign one test to it) whenever a room frees up; if the test taker has more tests left to take, then put it back on the queue.

One way to balance your execution times is to assign a random priority to your "test-takers," e.g.

```
testTaker.serPriority(random.Next(CONSTANT * testTaker.numberOfRemainingTests))
```

Then reset the test taker's priority whenever it completes a test.  This will favor assigning tests to test takers with more tests to take, while the random element will approximate fairness.  `CONSTANT` ought to be greater than the number of test takers to ensure sufficient randomness.